# Irreducible representation restricted to index 2 subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a (not nec. finite) group with *index 2* subgroup $H$ and $k$ is a field (possibly of positive characteristic). Suppose $$\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}_2(k)$$ is an *irreducible* 2-dimensional representation and suppose $\rho\mid_H\cong \psi_1\oplus\psi_2,$ where $\psi_i$ is a 1-dimensional representation.

Does it follow from general representation theory that $\rho\cong\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\psi_1)$? If so, how does one prove this? If no, can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the following form of Frobenius reciprocity: for every $k[G]$-module $V$ and every $k[H]$-module $U$, there is an isomorphism of groups
$$
{\rm Hom}_G(V,{\rm Ind}_{G/H}U) \cong {\rm Hom}_H({\rm Res}_{G/H}V,U).$$
So if the right hand side is non-trivial, then so is the left hand side. But if $V$ is a simple module (i.e. the representation is irreducible), then any homomorphism from it to anything is either 0 or injective, since the kernel of a hom is a submodule. So in your situation you have an injective homomorphism from $\rho$ to ${\rm Ind}_{G/H}\psi_1$. Since the two have the same dimension, this must be an isomorphism.

Comment: That's great, thanks!